# fix/escape javascript escape character?

Tags: javascript, .net

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396544/what-does-do-on-non-escape-characters/4396662#4396662) for reasoning why / is escaped and what happens on nonspecial characters

I have a string that looks like this after parsing. This string comes fron a javascript line.

```
var="http:\/\/www.site.com\/user"
```

I grabbed the inside of the quote so all i have is `http:\/\/www.site.com\/user`. How do i properly escape the string? so its `http://www.site.com/user`?  I am using .NET

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you are asking for a regular expression to do a string replace? Is the replacement happening with JavaScript or .NET?

Comment: @epascarello: I am asking for a function that escapes strings like `http:\/\/` properly. ex escapeit(@"http:\/\/")

Answer (score 1):

Use the [String.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method:

```
string expr = @"http:\/\/www.site.com\/user";  // That's what you have.
expr = expr.Replace("\\/", "/");               // That's what you want.
```

That, or:

```
expr = expr.Replace(@"\/", "/");
```

Note that the above doesn't replace occurrences of `\` with the empty string, just in case you have to support strings that contain other, legitimate backslashes. If you don't, you can write:

```
expr = expr.Replace("\\", "");
```

Or, if you prefer constants to literals:

```
expr = expr.Replace("\\", String.Empty);
```

Comment: i edited my question. The string is in a string already. i didnt copy/paste it from js but parsed it from reading a db which came from a js file :x

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it has the \ in it since `var foo = "http://www.site.com/user";` is a valid string.

If the \ characters are meant to be there for some strange reason, than you need to double them up

```
var foo = "http:\\/\\/www.site.com\\/user";
```

Comment: no no i need it to go the other way. i need \/ to become / but i dont want to write my own func bc i dont remember how to escape a js script.